# Is there a way of defining the order by which cdi is going to destroy instances?

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-7

I'm developing an application where I have some services being injected. Once the application shuts down, I would like to define an order by which my destroy() functions are called.

For instance, "Service A needs to shut down before service B".

Is there a way of doing such a thing?

Comment: Put the service references into a TreeMap with the key being the order of destruction. Then loop through the tree destroying each service, and putting in a short ```wait()``` between calls. Or ArrayList.

Comment: Just because I am curious: What do your `destroy()` functions actually do and why are these functions dependent on another service shutting down before? I always thought one of the main purposes of CDI is that you don't have to worry about such things.

Comment: @maio290 In this case I have one service that manages a list of objects. I have others that request and perform operations in this list of objects. When shutting down, it would be ideal that an order would be established. To be honest, this is a "nice to have", so I'm investigating the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have two objects, `A` and `B`, with no relationship to one another, in, say,  `@Singleton` scope (just an arbitrary scope).  To my knowledge there is no defined order around when their producing `Bean`s' `destroy()` methods will be called: `A` could be destroyed first or `B` could be destroyed first.

Suppose instead now you have these three objects:

1. `A` in `@Singleton` scope (again, an arbitrary scope)
2. `B` in `@Dependent` scope, injected into `A`
3. `C` in `@Dependent` scope, injected into `B`

In this case, again assuming we're talking about custom beans and not managed beans, `C` will be destroyed first, then `B`, then `A`.

To my knowledge that is the only ordering guarantee offered by the specification.

Comment: The general idea of of this answer is correct, however the notion of `managed bean` and `custom bean` is misused. See the spec definition [on managed beans](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#managed_beans). I am not sure what you mean by `custom bean` either because it usually means a custom implementation of the `Bean` interface (which is then registered via portable extension).

Comment: I thought that a managed bean class was represented by a `Bean` internally whose means of production, in turn, was represented by a `Producer` internally, and [such Producers' dispose() methods do nothing when destroy is called](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#injectiontarget).  My apologies for the misunderstanding.